# jQuery append two tds' in one tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

How to use jQuery to append only two tds' in a single tr ..

I have a table .. I want to max how many tds per row.. something like this

```
if($("td").length) == 0){ // get the count of existing tds
 $("table").append("<tr>");
}
   $("table").append("<td>Something</td>");

if($("td").length) == 2){ // if it hit two tds' in this tr then close the tag
 $("table").append("</tr>");
} // this is not a valid example, just trying to deliver my point
```

it's not a loop, it appends on click, so let's say I clicked **5** times, I should get this

```
<tr>
 <td>Someting</td>
 <td>Someting</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Someting</td>
 <td>Someting</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Someting</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is this all of your JavaScript code?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in more detail. `$("td").length)` gives total number of `TD` in page. Not clear what you want

Comment: I already mentioned this an invalid example, I'm trying to say that i only want the `append` to add two tds in one tr, if it hit two then create a new tr tag and close the current tag that already has two tds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
var max = 2
var tr = $("table tr:last");
if(!tr.length || tr.find("td").length >= max)
    $("table").append("<tr>");
$("table tr:last").append("<td>hi</td>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yLrE/

Comment: Should cache the table selector

Comment: accessing the DOM is expensive so anytime you can make less lookups you should take advantage. This of course doesn't matter for small pages, but it can be a pain to fix as you're page balloons.

Answer (score 1):

If `$("td").length` is even, create a new row, if not, append to the last row:

```
var $tds = $('table td');
var $target = $tds.last().parent();
if($tds.length % 2 === 0){
    $target = $('<tr />').appendTo('table > tbody');
}
$target.append("<td>Something</td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('bla').click(function() {
  if ($('td').length % 2) === 0)
    $('table').append('<tr />');
  $('table:last').append($('<td>Something</td>'));
});
```